# Can I automate clicking on a specific button on a website?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, button, automation

I have to click a specific button on a website every hour.

Here is the button code I find by inspecting it.

```html
<button id="disabledBump"
        class="solid-cta-button disabled"
        disabled=""
        style="display: inline-block;">Already bumped!</button>
<button id="bump"
        class="solid-cta-button"
        onclick="bump()"
        style="display: none;">Bump</button>
```

Comment: Do you have access to the codebase or is this someone else's website?

Comment: I doubt they control the JavaScript.

Comment: This is someone else's website! :(

Comment: You can use this https://www.browserless.io/

Answer (score 1):

Call [`.click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) inside an [interval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval):

```js
setInterval(() => document.getElementById('bump').click(), 1000*60*60);
```

Comment: One way to automate this would be to open devtools in Chrome (F12 on windows) and paste the above into the console and hit enter. Obviously you then need to keep the tab open for the lifetime that you need this automation.

Answer (score 0):

When I try this I get the following in the console

> setInterval (() => document.getElementById('refreshInput').click(), 1000*60*60);
> < 705